# whta is use of .Class method in ng.core.component in es5

Tags: javascript, angular

```
var app = ng.core.Component({
 selector:'myapp',
template:'<h1>helloworld</h1>'
}).
Class(
{
constructor:function()
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the angular2 quickstart guide:

> The Class method is where we implement the component itself, giving it properties and methods that bind to the view and whatever behavior is appropriate for this part of the UI.

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-the-component-file